# How to get percentages of observations above a certain value for individuals and groups?

Tags: r

I am new to R and looking for some help with my thesis!

The data I have are participant ID, The group they belong to (control or patient) and coordinates in the column “gaze” where values >0 are right and <0 are left.

The goal is to calculate the percentage of coordinates at the right and left side of space for each participant and the two groups.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(personID=rep(1,6),gaze=c(-0.104,-0.105,0.00550,0.00407,0.00119,0.0411),group=rep('control',6))
df
#  personID     gaze   group
#1        1 -0.10400 control
#2        1 -0.10500 control
#3        1  0.00550 control
#4        1  0.00407 control
#5        1  0.00119 control
#6        1  0.04110 control
```

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the 10 first rows for example of your dataframe and the expected output? It will be easier to help you this way

Comment: You could use `mean(x < 0)` or `prop.table(table(sign(x)))`, or several other methods. If you need more help than that, please, as fmarm says, share a little bit of sample data and also show what you have tried!

Comment: Thanks! I added some sample data to the question. I hope this is enough to get a sense of it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dplyr` package to get your answer

```
library(dplyr)
# create a new boolean column with TRUE where gaze >=0
df <- df %>% mutate(positive_gaze=(gaze>=0))

# group by personID and calculate mean of the new column
df %>% group_by(personID) %>% summarise(pct_positive = 100*mean(positive))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  personID pct_positive
#     <dbl>        <dbl>
#1        1         66.7

# similarly you could group by group
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(pct_positive = 100*mean(positive))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  group   pct_positive
#  <fct>          <dbl>
#1 control         66.7

# or group by both group and personID
df %>% group_by(group,personID) %>% summarise(pct_positive = 100*mean(positive))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   group [1]
#  group   personID pct_positive
#  <fct>      <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 control        1         66.7
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer, it’s working perfectly!